# Plot multiple locations in Google Maps on Blackberry

Tags: google-maps, blackberry

I have a BlackBerry app in which I want to load the Google Maps app. I have the code for plotting a single location, and now I want to plot multiple locations on the same map.

When I search, I found that multiple locations can be plotted with a kml file having multiple location coordinates. But this kml file should be available in a public URL. So that is not possible. Is there any other way to pass multiple locations simultaneosly?

Is it possible on BlackBerry?

Answer (score 0):

try blackberry maps demo (included in the blackberry simulator). it have the facility to show multiple locations.

Comment: I have tried Blackberry maps too.When i tried with two locations by using location document as mentioned in the docs,two markers are showing on the loaded screen.But it does'nt looks like a map,just as a blank screen with two markers.Why the map which is loaded correctly like Google maps?